# Cómo acceder al estado global desde varios componentes vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Quiero crear varios personajes en componentes divididos. mi duda es como puedo llamarlo a esa variable global sin repetir código. Tengo un array con 10 personajes.

**index.js**

```
state: {
characters: [],
charactersFilter: []},
 mutations: {
setCharacters(state, payload){
  state.characters = payload
},
setCharactersFilter(state, payload){
  state.charactersFilter = payload
}},
 actions: {
async getCharacters({commit}){
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2')
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    commit('setCharacters' , data.results)
    commit('setCharactersFilter' , data.results)
  }
  
  catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}},
```

**ListCharacters.vue**

```
export default {
components:{
     CardCharacter},

setup(){
const store = useStore()
const characters = computed(() => {
    return store.state.charactersFilter
})

 onMounted(() => {
    store.dispatch('getCharacters')
})

return {
    characters
}}}
```

**html de LisCharacters**

```
 <div class="characters">
    

          <h1>{{characters[0].name}}</h1> 
        
      </div>
```

lo que quiero es crear otro componente parecido al de ListCharacters pero nombrando al array 1 en  vez de cero. Pero no se como acceder desde otro componente a los personajes de character sin repetir todo el código del defaults.

He conseguido acceder a los datos del array 1 usando **.this**

```
 <h1>{{this.$store.state.characters[1]}}</h1>
```

Pero al intentar acceder al nombre de esta manera.

```
 <h1>{{this.$store.state.characters[1].name}}</h1>
```

Me da error diciéndome que no está definido.

Comment: Bueno, es un poco confuso lo que planteas. Cuando hablas de nombrar el "array 1 en vez de cero" te referis al indice? Probaste en lugar de ``<h1>{{characters[0].name}}</h1> `` armar un ciclo v-for?  algo raro que veo es la accion de tu store. No entiendo porqué una sola acción ejecuta las dos mutaciones. Esa parte esta de más, ya que siempre se van a cargar con los mismos datos. Deberia haber una acción por cada mutación. Asi como está planteado, siempre que hagas un getter a cualquiera de los dos estados vas a obtener el mismo listado de personajes.

Comment: Si obtiene lo mismo porqué queria hacer otra prueba de filtrado por búsqueda. Pero eso no es lo que quiero ahora solo quiero llamar desde otro componente al array 0. Porque quiero que cuando pinche en cada nombre me lleve a los datos de cada uno de los personajes por eso quiero aceder desde distintos componentes.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un componente que se llama `ListCharacters`, yo esperaría que en su html generase una lista de characters (ver [principio de least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)  ).

Lo anterior se haría con un v-for. De paso, como dijiste que querías que el nombre linkeara al perfil, harías algo como

```
<div class="characters">
   <div v-for="character in characters" :key="character.name">
      <a href="{{character.url}}">{{character.name}}</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Se podría hacer con componentes, por supuesto. Si hicieras un componente `CharacterLink`,  hijo de `ListCharacters`, que reciba `character` como prop desde el padre:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a href="{{character.url}}">{{character.name}}</a>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
    const {
      character
    } = defineProps({
      character: Object,
    });

</script>
```

Y en ListCharacters lo usarías como

```
<div class="characters">
   <character-link v-for="character in characters" :character="character" :key="character.name" />
</div>
```

La idea es que solamente ListCharacters conozca el array (que está leyendo desde el store). Si el componente link leyera directo del store... cómo podría saber en qué lugar de la lista está, y por tanto cuál es su índice?

Y cómo podría saber si ese índice existe en el store? Si lo pones en duro obviamente será undefined al inicio (el store está vacío). Razonemos un poco usando la [ley de deméter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

- CharacterLink tiene el deber de linkear un character. No es responsable de saber cuál. Eso se lo dice ListCharacters
- ListCharacters tiene el deber de listar un array. No tiene por qué almacenarlo. Para eso es el store.
- El store es responsable de almacenar los characters, pero a priori no sabe su contenido. Eso lo obtiene de un API externo.

Si tienes otro componente, como por ejemplo SearchCharacter, éste sí sería independiente, pero accedería a los datos igual que el listado, y su responsabilidad es listar un array filtrado (por tanto el array filtrado no es responsabilidad del store. Es una propiedad computada en el buscador)

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto creando varios **state** y commit con cada array del 0-9

**index.js**

```
commit('setLuke' , data.results[0]
```

**componente.vue**

```
<h1>{{this.$store.state.luke.name}}</h1>
```